# Database with sdk and eclipse

Tags: android

I want to know how to store vales while using android sdk with eclipse. For example if i create a login page, where will I store my values? Is it a regular database like mySQL or something else? How to use database with sdk?

Comment: if u want to store the info on ur phone itself then u can use either SQlite database or preferences else if u want it more like over the network then u can use sql, mysql, oracle ....databses

Comment: I'm developing the app on my laptop. So can I use mysql? But how will it get converted to apk file?

Comment: once you run your program it will automatically build an apk..go to bin folder inside your workspace folder. For example, my Eclipse workspace is under c:\Users\myandroid\workspace and my Eclipse Project is named AndroidApp. Therefore the AndroidApp.apk file will be located under c:\Users\myandroid\workspace\AndroidApp\bin\AndroidApp.apk

Comment: if u are using mysql then u will need
1) A server hosting ur databse(or u can use ur own laptop as database)
2) Mysql connector for connecting ur android app to the databse

Comment: which is the best option? So that my data is private?

Answer (score 0):

Please go through this link for various [Storage Options](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html) in android. Generally, how the apps are designed is they store the user credentials in a db that is present on the server. You make API calls through your android app and store the data there and fetch it when needed.